# Does Ubuntu automatically block visitors that do not have similar IP addresses?

Tags: networking, server

I set up a Node.js server on a Ubuntu machine, and it has an IP address of 172.18.x.x, I can visit the service over computers with 172.18.x.x yet some of the devices on the network has IPs of 172.19.x.x, and they are not able to visit the Ubuntu server. Does Ubuntu automatically filter requests and how do I disable this behavior?

I can confirm there is indeed a bridge between the subnet mask 172.19.0.0/16 and 172.18.0.0/16, when I run the same Node.js server on Mac or Windows, it does work as intended.

Comment: What are the subnet masks on these machines?  What is the network topology?  What do you mean by calling some of the devices "non-lan visitors" ?

Comment: They are very likely in another subnet without a router inbetween. If you want them to be able to communicate you have to add routes manually on each client. Or add a route on your router which connects those two subnets.

Comment: By "Node server" you mean a "Node.js server"? Generally, there is no firewall on Ubuntu installations. So, if a server runs (Node.js, other webserver, mail server, ...) it should be accessible by computers from LAN and wifi. Can you ping the server?

Comment: @molotow I cannot over 172.19.0.0/16.

Comment: @Ziazis I can confirm there is indeed a bridge between the subnet mask 172.19.0.0/16 and 172.18.0.0/16, when I run the same Node.js server on Mac or Windows, it does work as intended.

Comment: If you are using a static address on your machine it could be that there is no default gateway and with that no answer possible from the ubuntu machines side. What does the output `route` give you?

Comment: It would help if you stated the specific error you are encountering, in your question. As it stands, your question is quite vague based on assumption that it is doing something to specifically block the other subnet, and any number of issues could be the cause. A specific error message narrows this down and helps people to provide you a better answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is typically due to some type of third party firewall or security package on your Ubuntu installed by apt-get as a dependency or otherwise. Do a complete clean installation and see if this issue sticks.